# An ldapsearch from CentOS 8 to ldap server on CentOS 7 doesn't work

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap, centos8

Apparently, authselect has replaced authconfig on CentOS 8.2. Previously, on CentOS 7, installing

```
yum install -y openldap openldap-clients nss-pam-ldapd
```

configuring /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/openldap/ldap.conf, and running

```
authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=xx.xx.xx.xx --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --enablemkhomedir --update
```

would guarantee "ldapsearch -x" to work.  That's not the case with CentOS 8.2.

```
# authconfig --enableldap --enableldapauth --ldapserver=xx.xx.xx.xx --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --enablemkhomedir --update

Running authconfig compatibility tool.
The purpose of this tool is to enable authentication against chosen services with authselect and minimum configuration. It does not provide all capabilities of authconfig.

IMPORTANT: authconfig is replaced by authselect, please update your scripts.
See man authselect-migration(7) to help you with migration to authselect

Executing: /usr/bin/authselect check
Executing: /usr/bin/authselect current --raw
Executing: /usr/bin/authselect select sssd with-mkhomedir --force
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl enable sssd.service
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl stop sssd.service
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl start sssd.service
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl enable oddjobd.service
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl stop oddjobd.service
Executing: /usr/bin/systemctl start oddjobd.service

# ldapsearch -x
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

A Google search for what I'm missing or how to translate authconfig into authselect hasn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently RedHat didn't provide a replacement for the old *authconfig* command, however you can still configure your LDAP manually, src: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4271752